# How can I get special attribute value from tag by scrapy xpath method?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

My tag like below:

```
<a href="web address value" data-spe-type="aaa" />
```

I used  `response.xpath('otherpath/a/@href').get()` to fetch value it worked!
But I used `response.xpath('otherpath/a/@data-spe-type').get()` to fetch `data-spe-type` value, it got nothing! why?

Comment: Are you sure you did not make some typo mistake? Because what you presenting should work.

Comment: `@data-spe-type` value might be generated dynamically so you won't get it from source page